# The perfective verb опереться (to lean on) has the strangest conjugation in the future and imperative, what is the etymological reason for it?

Tags: глаголы, этимология, спряжение

From the impf/pf pair опираться/опереться (=to lean on), **опереться** seems to be the only verb that exhibits the following strange conjugations, though apparently belonging to the -e- conjugation group:

Future: **об**опру́сь / **об**опрёшься / **об**опру́тся (the prefix **об-** suddenly appears, with an apparent disappearance of the first mobile e in all forms?)

Past: опёрся / оперла́сь / опёрлись (no final **л** in the first person singular?)

Imperative: **об**опри́сь / **об**опрёмся / **об**опри́тесь (again, with the prefix **об-**?).

Could someone share the etymological or historical reason for such strange conjugations, in particular the appearance in the future and imperfective of the prefix **об-** and its meaning?

Comment: does it answer your question? https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/25355/134

Answer (score 2):

That topic is still controversial among academicians and other scientists.

There exist three similar prefixes in Russian: **о-**, **об-**, **обо-**. It's difficult to give a rule for these, and the only information of I know of is in [Efremova's dictionary](https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova-tolk/315656.html).

Native Russian speakers such as I usually differentiate the usage of these on a casual basis and what sounds best to the ear.

Comment: It might help to note that the "о-" changes to "обо-". I didn't get it at first, and was on the same track as the OP, wondering why an unrelated, additional "об-" appears before the "о-" of the stem